# How can you add and multiple to True or False?

Tags: python, boolean

I started learning python from a site, and it gave me a question that was kind of weird, I had to add and multiply a number to True and False. I've never done that before, so could someone explain what that means? (Can you replace True with 1 and False with 0?)

This is the question:

What is the value of result at the end of the following code?

```
x = 20
y = 5
result = (x + True) / (4 - y * False)
```

A)
False

B)
-21

C)
5

D)
5.25

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We expect you to do initial research before posting here, especially trying some of your own coding.  `print(True + 0)` would give you most of your desired information, as would looking up the integer values of Boolean constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 5.25 because in Python, True is equal to 1 while False is equal to 0.